# How do I could add additional header on Response Body

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc

Just see the code snippet of `SpringMVC-3.2.x` controller action method. Its quite easy to generate `JSON` but unable to add addtional custom header only for this action/specific action method for specific controller. not common for all `JSON` `@ResponseBody` action method .

```
@RequestMapping(value="ajaxDenied", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Map<String, Object> ajaxDenied(ModelMap model) {

    Map<String, Object> message = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    message.put("severity", "error");
    message.put("summary", "Restricted access only");
    message.put("code", 200);

    Map<String, Object> json = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    json.put("success", false);
    json.put("message", message);

    return json;
}
```

In the different way I could add additional headers as my demand but here is some problem in generating pure `JSON`. Its generate buggy `JSON` and able to parse few browser.

```
@RequestMapping(value="ajaxSuccess", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<String> ajaxSuccess(){
    Map<String, Object> message = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    message.put("severity", "info");
    message.put("location", "/");
    message.put("summary", "Authenticated successfully.");
    message.put("code", 200);

    Map<String, Object> json = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    json.put("success", true);
    json.put("message", message);

    String data = "";
    try {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        data  = mapper.writeValueAsString(json);
    } catch (Exception e) { //TODO
    }
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    headers.add("X-Fsl-Location", "/");
    headers.add("X-Fsl-Response-Code", "302");
    return (new ResponseEntity<String>(data, headers, HttpStatus.OK));
}
```

this action method could generate `JSON` String with escape character rather than pure `JSON` so depend on browser how it will be parse, Its cause failure for chrome. The output just look like

```
"{\"message\":{\"summary\":\"Authenticated successfully.\",\"location\":\"/\",\"severity\":\"info\",\"code\":\"200\"},\"success\":true}"
```

but our desired output

```
{
  "message":{
    "summary": "Authenticated successfully.",
    "location":"/",
    "severity":"info",
    "code":"200"
  },
  "success":true
}
```

I want to generate pure `JSON` with additional headers based on conditions for specific action of specific controller.

Comment: Why are you converting yourself? Let Spring handle that for you... Just return a `ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>` instead of `ResponseEntity<String>`, remove the mapper and let spring do the heavy lifting.

Comment: Yes you are right. I was stupid enough that unable to buildup such type of logic. Thanks a lots for your suggestion.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have the same problem after a dependency upgrade.  The body of my ResponseEntity<String> and the quotes are getting escaped with \.

Comment: Just follow the answer I hope you will get similar solution

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is the solution as the suggestion of  **M. Deinum**

```
@RequestMapping(value="ajaxSuccess", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> ajaxSuccess(){
    Map<String, Object> message = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    message.put("severity", "info");
    message.put("location", "/");
    message.put("summary", "Authenticated successfully.");
    message.put("code", 200);

    Map<String, Object> json = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    json.put("success", true);
    json.put("message", message);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    headers.add("X-Fsl-Location", "/");
    headers.add("X-Fsl-Response-Code", "302");
    return (new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(json, headers, HttpStatus.OK));
}
```

Answer (score 46):

You can add headers to the ResponseEntity builder. I think it is cleaner this way.

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;

// ...

@GetMapping("/my/endpoint")
public ResponseEntity myEndpointMethod() {

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json; charset=UTF-8");

    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .headers(headers)
            .body(data);
}
```

Comment: HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("AuthorizationToken", token);
        return new ResponseEntity("Authentication Successfull", headers, HttpStatus.OK);

Comment: Newer version of Spring returns ReadOnlyHttpHeaders, using this example will throw UnsupportedOperationException.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use `HttpServletResponse` for adding your status and headers in a more easy way:

```
@RequestMapping(value="ajaxSuccess", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String ajaxSuccess(HttpServletResponse response) {
  response.addHeader("header-name", "value");
  response.setStatus(200);
  return "Body";
}
```

Therefore you need to add following maven dependency **as provided**:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.53</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```