# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:null when setting header using response entity in spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am calling a web service which is returning me ResponseEntity object .Now I am  setting location header after getting HttpHeaders information from ResponseEntity.

```
responseEntity.getHeaders().setLocation(uriBuilder.path("/empl/{id}").buildAndExpand(empl.getEmpId()).toUri());
```

The above line of code is throwing java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException as headers is not modifiable. How can i set the location header in this particular case?

Comment: ensure that empl.getEmpId() returns non null value.

Comment: Headers seem to be immutable if you get it from `responseEntity`, look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/41482673

Comment: @Alien yeah it returns non null value. As mentioned by Kruschenstein  headers returned from responseEntity is non moidifiable as it is immutable

Comment: @Kruschenstein thanks for your comment. I thought there could a way of doing this after extracting header information from responseEntity. The solution in the link mentioned by you is what i have done ,setting header information before returning responseEntity

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I suggest to use:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/get-products-detail/", produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getProductsDetail(@RequestParam Long userToken, @RequestParam Long productId) {
        try {
            return ResponseEntity.ok().body(digitoonContentService.getProductsDetails(userToken, productId));
        } catch (InvalidTokenException e) {
            logger.info("token is null or invalid", e);
            MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.add("invalid_token", "true");
            ErrorDTO errorDTO = new ErrorDTO(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(), e.getMessage());
            return new ResponseEntity<Object>(errorDTO, headers, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
```